# deploying google maps v2 Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

i wanted to publish my google maps v2 in google play store, but to publish it, what do i need? 
i saw this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specify_app_settings_in_the_application_manifest but it does not have any details i need. i saw "Last updated January 17, 2014." at the above url so Google Maps v2 is still in use?

i have  heard that it was depreciated(i can run in my phone though) . when i choose a tag google-map-api-2 below it say it has been deprecated since may 19 2010. i'm afraid that i can run on my phone but it cannot works when i deploy to google play store.

i have use the sha1 fingerprint, default keystore, with my package name to create a API key. i then use that to create and display my map. i can run perfectly on my phone, display, zoom in out etc. but i wonder do i have to do anything else when i deploy to play store?

EDIT: i right click my application, export android application, create keystore. name the keystore password. then it tell me to name the apk file. i did it. then i go windows >  preferences > android > build > it is using defalut keystore, so i click browse on the custome keystore and go to the location of my new keystore. it says "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect" and i do not know how to go from there.

if it works, then how could i make my Maps work on other computer. or when publishing, what key do i need and where do i obtain them? there seems to be no steps on the internet, which makes me worry.

EDIT

[image]

the above screenshot is when i did the following steps. i right click > export android application> existing keystore. the keystore is the name of the keystore i created just now. the password i also entered and it match. so it means the computer is already using the keystore i created just now?

i click until this step and it shows the SHA1 fingerprint. so it is the fingerprint of this new keystore? if i click finish i can use this key and my package at at the console to create the new API key?like i did before with default keystore and SHA1 fingerprint. will that be done? what do i do about the destination file already exist? this is my first time deploying and creating a google map app so i am cautious about this stuff. i'm afriad one wrong step would make it unable to display my map.

the reason why i waited and not clicked finish is if it is done, will i be able to deploy it and use my map on other computer? also there are some files and is with my team and we are compiling later, so this project is not fully done, so do i export now or later? 
if i create this new API key using this new SHA1 fingerprint, will i be able to use it on this project and other project,(create new API key with this new SHA1 with different package name of differnet project. what i'm asking may not happen but i just wanted to be sure how this works and understand it. so sorry if there is too much question

**latest edit:** 
strange, there is a time where i go to the console and purposely use my old API key with a DIFFERENT package name then my project name and my map still displays. it is like the key does not matter. is it because i still have not deploy to google play store but is just developing?
also, i followed the steps and create a deploy.keystore. but then my team has some problsm ans requite me to put my codes in a new project, so i create a new keystore again. new.keystore. but at the location, the deploy.keystore and original debugkeystore file type is keystore, while my new.keystore is just file. so is it not a keystore? but when i uses the api, the map still runs. 
next, do i need to create a new keystore for every new project. can i just export and use existing keysore. browse for the deploy.keystore(not debug) again? i will only deploy one of the project though

also evertime i run my app on other computer, it requires me to download and import the google play services again. when i deploy my app, is the google play services in my application?

Comment: You need to make a distribution key and obtain the SHA1 fingerprint. In eclipse right click on projnct->Export android application ->Create key store. With the keystore you can obtain the SHA1 fingerprint and update the same in Google console where you have enable maps for your project.

Comment: i have followed your steps and updated my question..please have a look thanks.

Comment: try building from projnct->Export android application -> Use existing keystore

Comment: there seem to be progress. i edited again. the latest one is the screenshot and the explanation below.

Comment: the keystore which u have created will be the one which you would use while publishing on playstore.Once your app is live on playstore the maps can be viewed from any phone.For different project you will require different keystore

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation. so if i click finish, which Api key should i be using, new or old. to put in the android manifest? after i export, can i still modify my application? some codes etc. i click finish. but it is not using the keystore until i deploy my product?

Comment: You can make changes to your application...Just make sure that while uploading to playstore sign the apk with the keystore you have created..

Comment: ok thanks. signing means, when i deploy, it will prompt me for the keystore?

Comment: Yes...be sure to keep your key store safely... Once app is in playstore and you want to release update and if you lose the keystore you wont be able to update the application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a signing keystone and obtain the SHA1 fingerprint from it. In eclipse right click on project->Export android application ->Create key store. With the keystore you can obtain the SHA1 fingerprint and update the same in Google console where you have enable maps for your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to :

```
Create your own signing key that you will use for publishing, using Keytool :
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert

```
Get the MD5 fingerprint of your newly generated key :
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey#getfingerprint

```
Submit the signature to this link to get your Google Maps key :
```

https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup?hl=fr

Export your application with your newly created key, in Eclipse : right click on your projet -> Android Tools -> Export signed application package.

Be careful to keep your certificate in a safe place, because you will need it if you want to publish an update of your app on Google Play.

EDIT :

For the Google Maps Android V2, the signing is a little different. You will need to get the SHA-1 signature and provide the package name of your application as well. A Google APi account is moreover needed. All info are given on this page : 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=fr#the_google_maps_api_key

Comment: before your edit, it is about api v1 right, so main steps is in the link of your edit. but i have followed the steps. i have use the sha1 fingerprint, default keystore, with my package name to create a API key. i then use that to create and display my map. i can run perfectly on my phone, display, zoom in out etc. but i wonder do i have to do anything else when i deploy to play store? or maybe i did not see the link clearly where it states about publishing.

Answer (score -1):

Me too faced the same problem during releasing my app to google Play, when I used Google Maps V2 in my app. After succeeding the issue, I wrote a blog post regarding this you can have a [look](http://smdaudhilbe.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/how-to-create-release-keystore-digitally-sign-publish-android-app-to-google-play-android-market/).

As everyone requested, I would say the answer in following steps
1) Sign up your app using eclipse adt
2) Note down the SHA1 finger print which will be displayed at console of your eclipse adt
3) Again go to google console and get API_KEY for your app by using above got SHA1 fingerprint
4) Replace the old API_KEY with the new API_KEY on to manifest.xml of your app
5) Again sign up your app. Your app is ready to be published. But keep in mind that once you published your app to google market, you should be able to release updates to your app by signing **.apk** using the keystore which you used earlier for release.

Hope this helps ...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: strange, there is a time where i go to the console and purposely use my old API key with a DIFFERENT package name then my project name and my map still displays. it is like the key does not matter. is it because i still have not deploy to google play store but is just developing?